# GLM with random effect

Tags: r

I am fairly new to GLM. I can easily do glm analysis but right now I cant figure out script for GLM with random effect.

So I have this data with plants and soil carbon and nitrogen content of soil. However in some plot there are no plants and is barren land. I want to see the effect of plants on soil carbon and nitrogen content. Can I use random glm method to analysis this problem?

Thank you very much. 
This is what I am using right now but get error.

```
model=nlm(C~rye*Replication,data=data,random=~1|Replication/rye)
Error in nlm(C ~ rye * Replication, data = data, random = ~1 |  : 
  argument "p" is missing, with no default


plot crop   C    N  Treatment Replication rye carrot snap onion radish fava rape 
W1   Rye    1.1 0.1   Wed1         1       1    0      0    0     0      0    0
W2    0     1.3 0.1   Wed2         2       0    0      0    0     0      0    0
W3   Snap   1.2 0.2   Wed3         3       0    0      1    0     0      0    0 
W4   Onion  1.1 0.3   Wed1         1       0    0      0    1     0      0    0
W5   Radish 1.3 0.2   Wed2         2       0    0      0    0     1      0    0 
W6   0      1.2 0.1   Wed3         3       0    0      0    0     0      0    0
W7   rape   1.1 0.2   Wed1         1       0    0     0    0     0       0    1 
W8   Carrot 1.2 0.1   Wed2         2       0    1      0   0      0      0   0
W9   fava   1.2 0.1   Wed3         3       0    0      0   0      0      1   0
```

Comment: This won't work using `lm`. Where did you get the syntax for your random effects? It looks like something from the `nlme` package, which you would have to install and use, but you should refer back to wherever you got that random effects syntax and see if it mentions which packages and functions you should be using for this.

Comment: @Marius Sorry it is nlme. I have corrected it.

Comment: OK, so what is the error you get? You should include the full text of the error message in your question.

Comment: @Marius argument "p" is missing, with no default